# Is there any way that i could find all the oracle built in functions in a dictionary table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Is there any way that i could find all the oracle built in functions in a dictionary table?If this is so i could check the table instead of glancing numerous oracle's lengthy product  documentation.

Comment: You dont' have to "glance" at "numerous oracle's lengthy product documentation."  It's all documented in one place - the _SQL Language Reference_,  in the chapter "Functions".  And as @Littlefoot pointed out, you are going to need to go there anyway in order to find out what a given function does and how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for the data-dictionary view [`ALL_PROCEDURES`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/ALL_PROCEDURES.html#GUID-3DED0AD5-4220-4C77-AE16-07060A19E6DF), or perhaps `DBA_PROCEDURES`.

These views list all of the stored procedures and functions the user has access to (`ALL_PROCEDURES`) or all procedures and functions in the database (`DBA_PROCEDURES`, if you have access to it).

Comment: Thanks for the ans Luke, William Ed. I usually take help of the documentation for an unknown function. But what of i just wanted to know what are the new functions added in 12.2 or 19c,like gv$sql_hints,If i filter with version number i would get to know these are the new hints added to sql arsenal.My intention of the question is to know if such there is existence of such kind of function.

Comment: There is, and has always been, the "What's new" section in documentation, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/whats-new.html. That's "how".

Answer (score 2):

Just an example of what Luke has said.

If you query `ALL_PROCEDURES`, I believe that `object_name = 'STANDARD'` is the filter you're looking for. In my 11gXE:

```
SQL> select distinct procedure_name
  2  from all_procedures
  3  where object_name = 'STANDARD'
  4  order by procedure_name;

PROCEDURE_NAME
------------------------------
<snip>
ABS
ACOS
ADD_MONTHS
<snip>
REGEXP_COUNT
REGEXP_INSTR
<snip>
SOUNDEX
SQLCODE
SQLERRM
SQRT
SUBSTR
<snip>
TO_CHAR
TO_CLOB
TO_DATE
<snip>

181 rows selected.

SQL>
```

However, I still think that you should read documentation. What good does it make if you know that there's the `SUBSTR2` function, but you have no idea what it does nor what its parameters are?

Comment: You might also `join v$reserved_words r on r.keyword = p.procedure_name` to filter out a few package procedures/functions that aren't part of the SQL language.

Comment: Robertson - that helps. Thanks